# how to create a table on sql server with vb.net where the name is entered by the user

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, vb.net, datagridview

i want to create a table on sql server with vb.net but the server, database and table names should be entered by the user, to do so i tried to use a new form but the code is executed before entering the informations

here's my code

```
Form2.Show()
    Dim grid = DirectCast(Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls(0), DataGridView)
    Dim header As String = ""
    Dim sql As String
    connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & Form2.TextBox2.Text & ";Initial Catalog=" & Form2.TextBox3.Text & ";integrated security=true")
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In grid.Columns
        header = header & column.HeaderText & " varchar(50) NULL,"
    Next
    sql = "CREATE TABLE " & Form2.TextBox1.Text & "(" & header & ")"
    Dim Mycommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    Try
        Mycommand.Connection.Open()
        Mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Mycommand.Connection.Close()
    Catch
        MsgBox(" Already installed table")
    End Try
```

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using `ShowDialog` rather than `Show`.  `Show` will display the form and then continue executing the rest of the code while `ShowDialog` will block until the form is closed.